# Prove that $f(X\cap f^{-1}(Y))=f(X)\cap Y$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $\ f\colon A\to B$ and let $X\subset A$, $Y\subset B$, prove that
>   $$f(X\cap f^{-1}(Y))=f(X)\cap Y$$

The "$\subset$"$-$inclusion is easy: if $y\in f(X\cap f^{-1}(Y))$, exists a $x\in X\cap f^{-1}(Y)$ such that $f(x)=y$. Thus, $x\in X$ and $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$, and hence $f(x)\in f(X)$ and $f(x)\in Y$. This leads to $f(x)=y\in f(X)\cap Y$.

I'm having problems with the other inclusion. If I proceed the same way I get: if $y\in f(X)\cap Y$, then $y\in f(X)$ and $y\in Y$. Thus, exists a $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$, and exists a $x'\in f^{-1}(Y)$ such that $f(x')=y$. If $x=x'$, it's clear the result, but don't know whether $x=x'$.

I don't know what to do. I'll thank any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(x)=y\in Y$, we have $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$ by the definition of $f^{-1}(Y)$.  Also, $x\in X$ by construction.  Therefore $x\in X\cap f^{-1}(Y)$, so...